# What are all the three letter codes for the different emission designators?

Tags: modes, encoding

For example, A1A is "morse telegraphy by on-off keying". What are the others?

Comment: These are ITU codes, and thus have scope much greater than the UK.

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II I edited the title and tags to reflect your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in this article in the Wikipedia: [types of radio emissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_radio_emissions). From that article you can construct the different codes for different modes but there's a list of common examples:

- **A3E**: AM speech communication – used for aeronautical communications
- **F3E**: FM speech communication – often used for marine radio and many other VHF communications
- **20K0 F3E**: Wide FM, 20.0 kHz width, ±5 kHz deviation, still widely used for Ham Radio, NOAA weather radio, marine, and aviation users and land mobile users below 50 MHz [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_radio_emissions)
- **11K2 F3E**: Narrow FM, 11.25 kHz bandwidth, ±2.5 kHz deviation – All Part 90 Land Mobile Radio Service (LMRS) users operating above 50 MHz were required to upgrade to narrowband equipment by 2013-01-01. [2] [3] [4]
- **6K00 F3E**: Even Narrower FM, future roadmap for Land Mobile Radio Service (LMRS), already required on 700 MHz public safety band
- **J3E**: SSB speech communication, used on HF bands by marine, aeronautical and amateur users
- **R3E**: SSB with reduced carrier (AME) speech communication, primarily used on HF bands by the military (a.k.a. compatible sideband)
- **N0N**: Continuous, unmodulated carrier, formerly common for radio direction finding (RDF) in marine and aeronautical navigation.
- **A1A**: Signalling by keying the carrier directly, a.k.a. Continuous Wave (CW) or On-Off Keying (OOK), currently used in amateur radio. This is often but not necessarily Morse code.
- **A2A**: Signalling by transmitting a modulated tone with a carrier, so that it can easily be heard using an ordinary AM receiver. It was formerly widely used for station identification of non-directional beacons, usually but not exclusively Morse code (an example of a modulated continuous wave, as opposed to A1A, above).
- **F1B**: Frequency-shift keying (FSK) telegraphy, such as RTTY.[a]
- **F1C**: High frequency Radiofax
- **F2D**: Data transmission by frequency modulation of a radio frequency carrier with an audio frequency FSK subcarrier. Often called AFSK/FM.
- **J2B**: Phase-shift keying such as PSK31 (BPSK31)